# select from select postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a query like this

```
SELECT trx.store, trx.sales, trx.qty_sold, trx.average, trx.start_date, trx.end_date, stok.stok_qty
FROM
(select sto.name as store, sum(odi.subtotal_price) as sales, sum(odi.qty) as qty_sold, ((sum(odi.subtotal_price))/(sum(odi.qty))) as average, 
    min(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as start_date, max(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as end_date 
from trx_order_detail_item odi
left join trx_order as ord on ord.id = odi.order_id
left join mst_store as sto on sto.id = ord.store_id
where sto.principle_id = 12 and ord.date_out between '2018-07-01' and '2019-02-28' 
    and ord.order_status_id in (select mst_order_status.id from mst_order_status where mst_order_status.id = 3 or mst_order_status.id = 5) 
    and ord.void_status=0
group by sto.name, date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)
order by date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)) AS trx, 
(select sum(siss.jumlah_akhir) as stok_qty
from trx_stok_item_summary as siss 
where siss.input_date IN (select max(sisss.input_date)
            from trx_stok_item_summary as sisss
            join mst_store as sto on sto.id = sisss.store_id
            join mst_item as it on it.id = sisss.item_id
            join mst_item_classifiers as ic on ic.id = sisss.item_variant_id
            where sto.principle_id = 12 and input_date between '2018-07-01' AND  '2019-02-28'
            group by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date), sisss.item_variant_id
            order by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date))
group by date_trunc('month', siss.input_date)) AS stok
```

and the output is

```
Store  |Sales |qty_sold|average |start_date  |end_date    |stok_qty 
===================================================================
Store 1|494000|128     |3859.375|"2018-07-02"|"2018-07-31"|-263
Store 1|494000|128     |3859.375|"2018-07-02"|"2018-07-31"|0
Store 1|327000|44      |7431.818|"2018-08-01"|"2018-08-19"|-263
Store 1|327000|44      |7431.818|"2018-08-01"|"2018-08-19"|0
```

and when I extend the date the output is looping as much as how many month in the data range.

And the output that I want is:

```
Store  |Sales |qty_sold|average |start_date  |end_date    |stok_qty 
===================================================================
Store 1|494000|128     |3859.375|"2018-07-02"|"2018-07-31"|-263
Store 1|327000|44      |7431.818|"2018-08-01"|"2018-08-19"|0
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: it looks stok_qty is missed place or you have any logic to pick that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing any sort of join criteria, try:

```
SELECT trx.store, trx.sales, trx.qty_sold, trx.average, trx.start_date, trx.end_date, stok.stok_qty
FROM
(select sto.name as store, sum(odi.subtotal_price) as sales, sum(odi.qty) as qty_sold, ((sum(odi.subtotal_price))/(sum(odi.qty))) as average, 
    min(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as start_date, max(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as end_date,
date_trunc('month', ord.date_out) AS trx_month
from trx_order_detail_item odi
left join trx_order as ord on ord.id = odi.order_id
left join mst_store as sto on sto.id = ord.store_id
where sto.principle_id = 12 and ord.date_out between '2018-07-01' and '2019-02-28' 
    and ord.order_status_id in (select mst_order_status.id from mst_order_status where mst_order_status.id = 3 or mst_order_status.id = 5) 
    and ord.void_status=0
group by sto.name, date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)
order by date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)) AS trx, 
(select date_trunc('month', siss.input_date) AS stok_month,
sum(siss.jumlah_akhir) as stok_qty
from trx_stok_item_summary as siss 
where siss.input_date IN (select max(sisss.input_date)
            from trx_stok_item_summary as sisss
            join mst_store as sto on sto.id = sisss.store_id
            join mst_item as it on it.id = sisss.item_id
            join mst_item_classifiers as ic on ic.id = sisss.item_variant_id
            where sto.principle_id = 12 and input_date between '2018-07-01' AND  '2019-02-28'
            group by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date), sisss.item_variant_id
            order by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date))
group by date_trunc('month', siss.input_date)) AS stok
WHERE stok.stok_month = trx.trx_month
```

Answer (score 0):

use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct trx.store, trx.sales, trx.qty_sold, trx.average, trx.start_date, trx.end_date, stok.stok_qty
FROM
(select sto.name as store, sum(odi.subtotal_price) as sales, sum(odi.qty) as qty_sold, ((sum(odi.subtotal_price))/(sum(odi.qty))) as average, 
    min(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as start_date, max(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) as end_date 
from trx_order_detail_item odi
left join trx_order as ord on ord.id = odi.order_id
left join mst_store as sto on sto.id = ord.store_id
where sto.principle_id = 12 and ord.date_out between '2018-07-01' and '2019-02-28' 
    and ord.order_status_id in (select mst_order_status.id from mst_order_status where mst_order_status.id = 3 or mst_order_status.id = 5) 
    and ord.void_status=0
group by sto.name, date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)
order by date_trunc('month', ord.date_out)) AS trx, 
(select sum(siss.jumlah_akhir) as stok_qty
from trx_stok_item_summary as siss 
where siss.input_date IN (select max(sisss.input_date)
            from trx_stok_item_summary as sisss
            join mst_store as sto on sto.id = sisss.store_id
            join mst_item as it on it.id = sisss.item_id
            join mst_item_classifiers as ic on ic.id = sisss.item_variant_id
            where sto.principle_id = 12 and input_date between '2018-07-01' AND  '2019-02-28'
            group by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date), sisss.item_variant_id
            order by date_trunc('month', sisss.input_date))
group by date_trunc('month', siss.input_date)) AS stok
```

Comment: "stok_qty"  is different, distinct will not help

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (store, start_date) . . .
<rest of your query here>
order by store, start_date, stok_qty;
```